# Pass value into template name XSLT

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have a template like this:

```
<xsl:template name="TextInput">
    <div>TextInput type template called</div>
</xsl:template>
```

And I have a loop:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns:questionParts">

    <xsl:call-template name="ns:type"/>

</xsl:for-each>
```

In which `ns:type` corresponds to the different name. In this case `ns:type` is equals to `TextInput`. But I can have more different types. So I am trying to create different templates for each type so that I can call a template depending on the type. Directly passing `ns:type` into a template name is not working I am getting: `"[FATAL]: Could not compile stylesheet"`. Is there anyway I can achieve this? To pass a type from the element directly into a template name?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do dynamic despatch in XSLT is using `xsl:apply-templates`, not `xsl:call-template`.

Replace

```
<xsl:template name="TextInput">
    <div>TextInput type template called</div>
</xsl:template>
```

by

```
<xsl:template match="ns:type[.='TextInput']">
    <div>TextInput type template called</div>
</xsl:template>
```

and replace

```
<xsl:call-template name="ns:type"/>
```

by

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="ns:type"/>
```